# Sqlite Agregar una llave foránea a una tabla ya existene

Tags: sql, sqlite

Voy adicionar una llave foránea en la tabla participa. Pero me arroja el error:
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "FOREIGN": syntax error

El codigo de alteración que estoy ejecutando es

```
ALTER TABLE Participa ADD FOREIGN KEY(rut) REFERENCES Persona(rut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la sintaxis para agregar una restrcción de clave foránea a una tabla que ya existe en SQL-92 es:

```
ALTER TABLE NombreTabla
ADD CONSTRAINT NombreRestriccion
FOREIGN KEY (Columna1, ... ,ColumnaN)
REFERENCES NombreTablaReferencia(ColumnaF1, ..., ColumbaFN);
```

Sqlite no soporta la creación de restricciones de clave foranea mediante sentencia de alteración (`ALTER TABLE`) https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Por lo que para obtener una clave foranea debe:

1. Crear en una tabla temporal una copia de los datos de la tabla sobre la cual desea crear la clave foránea (Esto, si tiene ya datos en dicha tabla).
2. Eliminar (`DROP TABLE`) la tabla sobre la cual desea crear la clave foranea
3. Crear una nueva tabla con el mismo nombre de la tabla en la que deseaba crear la foranea inicialmente; ahora agregando la definición de la clave foranea durante la creación con la siguiente sintaxis

```
CREATE TABLE NombreTabla (
   -- Definición de Colomnas
   , CONSTRAINT NombreRestriccionGoranea
     FOREIGN KEY (Columna1, ..., ColumnaN)
     REFERENCES NombreTablaReferencia(ColumnaF1, ..., ColumnFN)
)
```

Con lo que se crea una restricción de clave foránea en la tabla `NombreTabla` que garantiza que para cada fila de dicha tabla que tiene valores no nulos en sus columnas `Columna1` a `ColumnaN` existe una fila en  la tabla `NombreTablaReferencia` cuyas columnas `ColumnaF1` a `ColulimnaFN` contienen los mismos valores.

Para cumplirse esta última condiciòn solo se requiere que la tabla `NombreTablaReferencia` tenga una clave primaria (`PRIMARY KEY`) , clave única (`UNIQUE`) o índice único (`UNIQUE INDEX`) sobre el conjunto de columnas `ColunnaF1` a `ColumnaFN` de la tabla `NombreTablaReferencia`

Para su caso particular la re-reación de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Participa (
    --Definicion de Columnas
    , CONSTRAINT NombreForanea 
      FOREIGN KEY(rut)
      REFERENCES Persona(rut)
);
```

4. Volver a poblar los datos de la nueva tabla con los datos de la tabla temporal que se obtuvo como copia inicialmente

Cabe anotar que si la tabla que referencia (en su caso particular `Persona`) no cumple las condiciones de que sea clave única, debe proceder a re-crearla del mismo modo porque la creación de claves primarias por alteración tampoco es sopprtado por Sqlite